# Permissions - Can I enable/disable the “Inherit Security settings from parent’ option for a folder via core service?

Tags: 2011, core-service

**Permissions**

Can I enable/disable the "Inherit Security settings from parent" option for a folder via core service? I searched for options here in `folderData.IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot`.

Please correct me know if I am wrong here.

Also , can I get owning repository /publication of a folder via core service  ?

Answer (score 7):

OrganizationalItemData has a property .IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot that you can use for this.

Comment: I have tried the below and permissions are not getting set in the Tridion CME. Am I missing something ? folderData.IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot= false;            
client.Save(folderData, new ReadOptions());

Comment: Just FYI: Setting it to "false" ("not a new root") means that it will inherit the security from its parent, which is the default. It sounds like you were looking for the opposite, in which case you will want to specify "true".

Comment: Peter is right. The following should give you what you need:                   folder.IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot = true;

Answer (score 6):

IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the item inherits permissions from the parent item.

For the second question - use

```
folder.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository
```

(I assume that folder is of type FolderData)

Comment: I have tried the below and permissions are not getting set in the Tridion CME. Am I missing something ? folderData.IsPermissionsInheritanceRoot= false;            
client.Save(folderData, new ReadOptions()); thanks for the second answer, am able to retrieve the owning repository.

Comment: Sorry - I had to specify all description from documentation.
 <value><c>true</c> if permissions are specified for item itself; otherwise, <c>false</c>, if item inherits permissions from the parent item.</value>